# Solvability of ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{C})/\mu_n$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer and $\mu_n$ is the group of $n$th roots of unity. Is it true that the group ${\rm GL}_2(\mathbb{C})/\mu_nI_2$ is solvable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your group has, as a quotient,
$$PGL_2(\mathbb{C}) = GL_2(\mathbb{C}) / \mathbb{C} I_2
$$
which is not solvable (it is isomorphic to the group of isometrics of hyperbolic 3-space $\mathbb{H}^3$ which, by standard [ping-pong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping-pong_lemma#Special_linear_group_example) arguments, contains a free group of rank 2).

So, since your group has a nonsolvable quotient, it is not solvable itself.

Comment: A rather simpler argument shows that it contains a perfect group.